# Hiding constructors of data type

Tags: haskell, interface, module, abstraction

When importing some data type, it is necessary to put (..) for constructors to be imported.

Is it possible to prevent exporting constructors of some data type, even when that data type is exported?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, just use the same syntax when exporting them - `Foo()` just to export the type, `Foo(..)` to export the type and all constructors, and `Foo(FooC1,FooC2)` to just export the named constructors of the type.

Comment: Just "Foo" in the export list is enough to omit the constructors.

Comment: @Anthony: A fact that I rediscover on a regular basis, by first forgetting it, then wondering why my constructors aren't in scope...

Comment: FWIW I prefer being explicit that I'm exporting no constructors.